# Azure PaaS ARM template installation error - "Invalid URI: The URI is empty"

Tags: azure, paas, arm-template

Could anybody please help on below.
I'm getting below error after 1 hour of execution in powershell script  while installing sitecore on Azure PaaS using ARM template but I can access CM and CD server after this.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:49:54 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/extensions 'demo-sc901azure2-cm/MSDeploy' failed with message '{
"status": "failed",
"error": {
"code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
"message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.",
"details": [
{
"code": "Failed",
"message": "AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.\r\n at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, 
UriKind uriKind)\r\n at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from 
previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'"
}
]
}
}'
At D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:123 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:49:54 PM - AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'
At D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:123 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

VERBOSE: 11:49:54 PM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites 'demo-sc901azure2-exm-dds' provisioning status is succeeded
VERBOSE: 11:49:54 PM - Resource Microsoft.Resources/deployments 'demo-sc901azure2-application' provisioning status is succeeded
VERBOSE: 11:49:55 PM - Checking deployment status in 60 seconds

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:51:10 PM - Resource Microsoft.Resources/deployments 'demo-sc901azure2-application-exm' failed with message '{
"status": "Failed",
"error": {
"code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
"message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
"details": [
{
"code": "DeploymentFailed",
"message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage 
details.",
"details": [
{
"code": "Conflict",
"message": "{\r\n \"status\": \"failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource operation 
completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"Failed\",\r\n \"message\": \"AppGallery Deploy 
Failed: 'System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.\\r\\n at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)\\r\\n at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadPackageAndSettings&gt;d__26.MoveNext()\\r\\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where 
exception was thrown ---\\r\\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\\r\\n at 
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\\r\\n at 
Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__17.MoveNext()'\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"
}
]
}
]
}
}'
At D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:123 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11:51:10 PM - At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see 
https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
At D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\tools\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1:123 char:35
+ ... eployment = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $Name -ResourceG ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

The file azuredeploy.parameters.json has the following parameters

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

"parameters": {
    "deploymentId": {
      "value": ""
    },
"location": {
  "value": "East US"
},
    "sitecoreAdminPassword": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "licenseXml": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "repAuthenticationApiKey": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "sqlServerLogin": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "sqlServerPassword": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "cmMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "cdMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "prcMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "repMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "xcRefDataMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "xcCollectMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "maOpsMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "maRepMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    }, 
    "deployExmDds": {
      "value": true
    },
    "exmDdsMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "exmCmMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "authCertificateBlob":{
      "value": ""
    },
    "authCertificatePassword":{
      "value": "ProvidedValue"
    },
    "sitecoreSKU":{
      "value": "Small"
    }
  }
}
```

Powershell script that looks like

```
$SCSDK="D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\tools"
$SCTemplates="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/master/Sitecore%209.0.1/XP"
$DeploymentId = "demo-sc901azure"
$ResourceGroup = "demo-sc901azurerg"
$LicenseFile = "D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\license.xml"
$CertificateFile = "ProvidedValue"
$SubscriptionId = "ProvidedValue"
$Location="East US"
$ParamFile="D:\sitecore9_azure_PaaS\azuredeploy.parameters.json"
$Parameters = @{
"deploymentId"=$DeploymentId;
"authCertificateBlob" = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($CertificateFile))
}
Import-Module $SCSDK\Sitecore.Cloud.Cmdlets.psm1
Add-AzureRMAccount
Set-AzureRMContext -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId
Start-SitecoreAzureDeployment -Name $ResourceGroup -Location $Location -ArmTemplateUrl "$SCTemplates/azuredeploy.json" -ArmParametersPath $ParamFile -LicenseXmlPath $LicenseFile -SetKeyValue $Parameters -Verbose
```

Comment: Hello Hari, based on the error, one of your URIs is empty. Are you able to post any of your configuration for helping others guide you? Make sure to remove any private information before you do so...

Comment: thanks a lot for kind response. I edited post with required details.

Comment: Hari, you may wish to use a code block so that your configuration is more readable. Right now, it all collapses into a single big blurb of text :)

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. updated with proper format. thanks

Comment: Open Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, connect to your subscription, access your blob container, right-click on the uploaded deployment package file and select "Get Shared Access Signature". When you finish the steps, you should have a suffix that needs to be added to the default package URL. Have you tried this? Also try providing the URLs with signature suffix in the azuredeploy.json file.

Comment: I have provided Shared Access Signature Url in json file and seems this part is working fine as this error occurred at the last after 1 hour of installation. it should not be related to access issue for deploy package.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because there is no value set for the parameter cmMsDeployPackageUrl.

That parameter is usually link to a private blob storage of the sitecore CM (cloud) package.

Please see the [guide](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/sitecore_on_azure/deploying/walkthrough_deploy_a_new_sitecore_environment_to_the_microsoft_azure_app_service) and set all required parameters.

Comment: I have provided Share Access Signature Url from Storage Account for all required parameters related to PackageUrl. I replaced actual value by ProvidedValue as I don't want to share real one.